# Add percentages to the pie chart label in dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a pie chart for which I want to add percentages to the label. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vz64xbmw/22/) of the pie chart and the code is below. Right now the chart shows the actual values. I looked at the [**dc.js Getting Started and How-To Guide**](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) which is an example of a dashboard. It has the chart with percentages in the label. However, when I try to replicate the structure I get an error. For example, when I use the label function like so

```
.label(function(d) {if(all.value){return d.key + " " + d.value / all.value();}
.renderLabel(true)
```

in the console it says that all is not defined. Also, the `d.key` returns nothing as well. I guess my data has a different structure. Help appreciated. Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id='Chart'>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);

var XDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.Category;
});

var YDimension = XDimension.group();

dc.pieChart("#Chart")
    .width(480).height(300)
    .dimension(XDimension)
    .group(YDimension)
    .label(function(d){return d.value});

dc.renderAll();
```

**Data**

```
var data = [{
    Category: "A",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "4"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "4"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "4"
},{
    Category: "C",
    ID: "5"
}];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were close! In cases like this, I'd recommend doing something like the following:

```
.label(function(d) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
})
```

to get a feel for the structure of your data. If you do so, you'll see that `key` and `value` are under `d.data`, so you could have a label like

```
.label(function(d) {
    return d.data.key + ' ' + d.data.value + '%';
})
```

If you just want to calculate the fraction of the circle being displayed, you can use the `startAngle` and `endAngle` properties.

```
.label(function(d) {
    return d.data.key + ' ' + Math.round((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / Math.PI * 50) + '%';
});
```

`(d.endAngle - d.startAngle)` will give you the number of radians the slice is displaying, so you can calculate a percentage from there by dividing by the number of radians in a circle.

Comment: the console.log(JSON.stringify(d)) is very useful. thanks. Yet, I have to calculate the percentages because as of right now I have just the counts. Even using the console log I did not find the all.value() in the data which I need to get the percentages unless there is another way. You answer my question about how to concatenate keys and values, but the percentages part is the most vital one.

Comment: Edited to include how to check what percent of the circle is showing.

Comment: Wow thats actually a smart solution. What I did was I just used the length of the `data` object and then divided by it, but your way is more reliable. Thanks. Hopefully, they will turn it into a function or something, so its less work.

Comment: ``.label(function(d)`` does not have ``d.data`` it only has the ``d.key``

Answer (score 1):

`.label` is the right way to modify BUT pie chart has bug,
Check by log on d

```
.label(d => {
    console.log(d);
    // {
    //  key: 'which you return in dimension',
    //  value: 'ex: 259.91'
    // }
})
```

Ex, have 6 objs in array, BUT log may just 3 or 4 of them @@
To work around this bug

```
.on('pretransition', function(chart){
    chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(d => {
        console.log(d);
        // {
        //  data: {
        //      key: 'which you return in dimension',
        //      value: 'ex: 259.91'
        //  },
        //  endAngle: 'xxx',
        //  startAngle: 'yyy'
        // }
    })
})
```

[d obj inside text()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtNTV.png)

By this way we can log enough 6 objs in array
The label text is return val inside `text(d => {})`

```
chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d){
    let label = d.data.key;
    return label + ': ' + Number(d.data.value).toFixed(2);
})

//Or play with percentage
chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d){
    return d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it does not have d.data. Instead I use the .renderlet() :
:

```
.renderlet(function(chart){
        chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text( function(d) {
        return d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
        })
    })
```