# Print Percentage of measure value on the Pie Chart label in dc.js

Tags: dc.js

Dimension 'dim_pie' is passing any character value and Measure 'fact_pie' is passing any integer type value.

So how can i display the percentage of Measure value on label of pie-chart and how can i partition all pie slice based on sum of measure value ?

var ndx = crossfilter(datachart);

```
  var dim_pie = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Opportunity_Name;});
  var fact_pie = dim_pie.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.Amount;});     

   PieChart
      .width(300)
      .height(400)
      .dimension(dim_pie)
      .group(fact_pie)
      .innerRadius(30)
      .renderLabel(true)
      .label(function(d){  return d.key + " : " + d.value + " - " +(d.value / ndx.groupAll().reduceCount().value() * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"; })
      .colors(d3.scale.ordinal().range([ "red", "#006400" ]))
       ;
```

Data:
Opportunity_Name    Amount
Accenture           10
Apple               80
Cognizant           80
CTS                 20
Dell                60
Facebook            40
Google              20
Hp                  20
Hp                  10
IBM                 30
LinkedIn            10
Oracle              90
TCS                 10
Wipro               80
Wipro               10

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the first part of your question. Are you having trouble using [`.label()`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+label)? Since this is a dc.js question I don't think your crossfilter code is relevant here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add percentages to the pie chart label in dc.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209971/add-percentages-to-the-pie-chart-label-in-dc-js)

Answer (score 1):

Please add this code to your pie chart.

```
.label(function(d) { return d.key +" (" + Math.floor(d.value / all.value() * 100) + "%)"; });
```

This will display percentages of your measure values in brackets along with the key name.

Comment: Sorry, i am getting one small error.

ReferenceError: all is not defined 
.label(function(d) { return d.key +" (" + Math.floor(d.value / all.value() * 100...

So, can you help with this error how to define 'all' ?

Comment: Have you defined the all variable?
var all = ndx.groupAll();